# How to Group Data of a My SQL Table on the Basis of Four Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
I have a table named inventory_store.

Table name: inventory_store


date        invoice_no  permit_no   quantity  item_name

2014-01-21    121         111          10      A

2014-01-21    121         111          40      B

2014-01-21    121         111          10      C

2014-01-21    121         111          20      C 


2014-01-21    122         112          20      A

2014-01-21    122         112          30      B

2014-01-21    122         112          60      C

2014-01-21    122         112          20      C
```

i want to merge data on the basis of four column(date,invoice_no,permit_no,item_name) of table  inventory_store,and want to get output like i have shown below.

```
OUTPUT:

date        invoice_no    permit_no    total_quantity(A+B)  total_quantity(C)

2014-01-21   121           111           50                   30

2014-01-21   122           112           50                   80
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select date, invoice_no, permit_no,
       sum(case when item_name in ('A', 'B') then quantity else 0 end) as A_B,
       sum(case when item_name in ('C') then quantity else 0 end) as C
from inventory_store
group by date, invoice_no, permit_no
order by date, invoice_no, permit_no;
```

Comment: :Thanks its working fine..one more thing instead of writing (A,B,D..etc) can we give something except C(if i want sum of all items except C in fist sum statement).

Comment: You can use `item_name <> 'C'` instead (assuming the value is never `NULL`.